# Can't find debug apk

Tags: android, apk

I have write a first simple android project using Android Studio and tested well on AVD emulator.
The I use AS build APK and adb install -r myapk.apk in command line.
The response display "Success".
While I can't find my APP on the phone. 
My AVD emulator and my test device is not the same type.
On emulator, after installed, my test app pop up automatically.

[image]

While on real device, I can't find anything. Do I need to sign it?

AndroidManifest.xml is like below. This is an first example from Android tutorial. No much more except for 2 activities.

[image]

The code is from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). I only made minor change. After build in success I installed it to the phone. Can any apk be installed to a Android phone without any censer like APPLE?

I found the icon.

[image]

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: Try to install it with AS directly (pressing the green "arrow" button on the top bar). But what did you do exactly to find the app as you said you can't find it?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have missed to set icon in manifest file